# Opposite of asyncio.to_thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio

How do I run asynchronous function in blocking style? I am not allowed to modify signature of my mock function `f1()` and can't easy switch to async def and so can't use await expression.

```
async def cc2():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await asyncio.to_thread(print, "qwerty")

def f1():
    t = asyncio.create_task(cc2())
    # wait until the task finished before returning

async def main():
    f1()  # typical call from many places of a program

asyncio.run(main())
```

I tried `asyncio.get_running_loop().run_until_complete(t)`, but the hack does not work and I get the next error.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
>     return loop.run_until_complete(main)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
>     return future.result()
>   File "<stdin>", line 2, in main
>   File "<stdin>", line 3, in f1
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 618, in run_until_complete
>     self._check_running()
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 578, in _check_running
>     raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I run asynchronous function in blocking style?

If you are in sync code, you can call it with `asyncio.run(async_function())`. If you are in async code, you can `await async_function()` or `asyncio.create_task(async_function())`, with the latter scheduling it to run in the background. You are not allowed to use `asyncio.run()` (or `run_until_complete`, even with a newly created event loop object) inside async code because it blocks and could halt the outer event loop.

But if you need it for testing purposes, you can always do something like:

```
# XXX dangerous - could block the current event loop
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    pool.submit(asyncio.run, async_function()).result()
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea with ThreadPoolExecutor. As expected, this is not universal solution, but when the coroutine is standalone and does not depend on calling code, it is okay and completely suitable in my case, especially for fast testing.

Comment: @mymedia Exactly - it's a gross hack, but if you know what you're doing, it can get the job done. (You can also use ordinary threads, but then you have to manually transfer the return value and the exceptions, which is why I proposed the executor from c.futures.) Another option is the [`nest_asyncio`](https://pypi.org/project/nest-asyncio/) package, but I'd avoid that one because it uses monkeypatching to go against explicit design decisions of asyncio, so it's even more of a hack than using threads.